# Why is my button PySide2 not working in Python?

Tags: python, pyside2

In my PySide2 application there is a `downloadCodesButton` button clicking on which should execute a function in a separate QThread thread and display a value in a `countCodesLabel` label. But after clicking on the button nothing happens. Why?

My code:

```
import random
import colorama
import time
import os
import sys
import design
import tempfile
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Threads(QtCore.QObject):
    running = False
    downloadCodesReadySignal = QtCore.Signal(str, object)
    myvar = None

    def __init__(self, myvar, parent=None):
        self.myvar = myvar
        super().__init__()

    def downloadCodes(self):
        countCodes = 0
        with open(self.myvar, 'r') as f:
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                codes.append(line)
                countCodes = countCodes + 1
                line = f.readline()
        self.downloadCodesReadySignal.emit(countCodes)

class WarGenApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.downloadCodesButton.clicked.connect(self.downloadCodes)

    @QtCore.Slot(str, object)
    def downloadCodesReady(self, countCodes):
        self.countCodesLabel.setText(str(countCodes))


    def downloadCodes(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Открыть файл', '', 'Text files (*.txt)')[0]
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.Threads = Threads(myvar=fname)
        self.Threads.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.Threads.downloadCodesReadySignal.connect(self.downloadCodesReady)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.Threads.downloadCodes)
        self.thread.start()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = WarGenApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're referencing to `myvar` in the function `downloadCodes` of `Threads`, but that doesn't exist in the scope of that function.

Comment: @musicamante Do you mean that I need to replace myvar with self.myvar? After all, I declare the variable myvar at the beginning of the Threads class and in __init__ I assign it a value

Comment: change to `with open(self.myvar, 'r') as f:`

Comment: @eyllanesc I changed, but it seems to me the problem is in something else. Because after pressing the button, the amount of RAM increases and reaches its maximum and the load on the processor increases, although there is only one line in the file

Comment: You need to put parenthesis for `readline`s.

Comment: @Asocia Really thanks. But the main problem was not solved, by debugging I found out that the function ```downloadCodes``` of  ```Threads``` is executed, but the slot of this function ```downloadCodesReady``` is not

Comment: Did you change your code with what suggested here? If so, can you please edit your question with changes?

Comment: @Asocia Yes, I edited

Comment: @Erytho Your `downloadCodesReadySignal` has a signature `(str, object)` but you are trying to emit an `int`. This should be the problem. Change your signal's and slot's signature to `int`

Comment: @Asocia I just chandged ```self.downloadCodesReadySignal.emit((countCodes))``` to ```self.downloadCodesReadySignal.emit(str(countCodes))```, but problem was in signal's and slot's signature, because it`s ```(str, object)```, but I execute only with ```str``` and ```object``` isn`t. Thx for help)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at passing information into the slot. `QtCore.Signal(str, object)` expects a string and a object, but you only pass an `object`. Just change the `@QtCore.Slot(str,object)` to `@QtCore.Slot(object)` and adjust the signal calls accordingly and everything should work. Also, it might be a good idea to terminate the thread when it is done.

```
@QtCore.Slot(object)
def downloadCodesReady(self, countCodes):
    self.countCodesLabel.setText(str(countCodes))
    self.thread.terminate()
```

Finally, you are appending some undefined `codes` list in the `downloadCodes` function.

```
def downloadCodes(self):
    countCodes = 0
    with open(self.myvar, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            # codes.append(line) This one crashes the code
            countCodes = countCodes + 1
            line = f.readline()
    self.downloadCodesReadySignal.emit(countCodes)
```

Eventhough the thread crashes, it does not automatically terminate itself. It just seems, that nothing happens. Might be a good idea to add some exit condition in case the code won't run to safely exit and terminate the thread.